# Rails is generating an error when loading Opal Javascript on actual server but not on local test server

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, opalrb

I am using Opal to convert Ruby into Javascript on a Rails server, and everything works perfectly on the test server on my local machine in both development and production modes. However, when the files are uploaded to the actual server, an `ActionView::Template::Error` with no message is generated. The line that it indicates is the line in which the Javascript (Opal) is loaded, and indeed when that line is removed, the error disappears (although this is obviously not a solution). All the files on the server are the same as the files on the local machine, except the `bin`, `db`, `log` and `tmp` folders and the `Gemfile.lock` file.

I think that this may be a caching issue, because initially it was only the files that had been changed that were not working, but I can't be sure because now all the files are broken.

I have tried deleting the `tmp` folder, using `gem pristine --all` and using `gem update`, but none of these have helped.

I have been trying to find a solution, but there is no error message and I don't know where to start.

Also, the server did work before, but the recent change (in which scripts were converted to Opal) broke it.

This is one of many similar error messages in the error log:

```
I, [2016-09-15T11:24:58.760385 #18949]  INFO -- : [36ec2f26-e1ac-43a1-b3c9-2e211c80bedb] Started GET "/" for 123.211.235.196 at 2016-09-15 11:24:58 +0000
I, [2016-09-15T11:24:58.762917 #18949]  INFO -- : [36ec2f26-e1ac-43a1-b3c9-2e211c80bedb] Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
I, [2016-09-15T11:24:58.766164 #18949]  INFO -- : [36ec2f26-e1ac-43a1-b3c9-2e211c80bedb]   Rendering welcome/index.haml within layouts/application
I, [2016-09-15T11:24:58.768033 #18949]  INFO -- : [36ec2f26-e1ac-43a1-b3c9-2e211c80bedb]   Rendered welcome/index.haml within layouts/application (1.7ms)
I, [2016-09-15T11:25:15.383874 #18949]  INFO -- : [36ec2f26-e1ac-43a1-b3c9-2e211c80bedb] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 16620ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
F, [2016-09-15T11:25:15.388426 #18949] FATAL -- : [36ec2f26-e1ac-43a1-b3c9-2e211c80bedb]
F, [2016-09-15T11:25:15.388528 #18949] FATAL -- : [36ec2f26-e1ac-43a1-b3c9-2e211c80bedb] ActionView::Template::Error ():
F, [2016-09-15T11:25:15.388756 #18949] FATAL -- : [36ec2f26-e1ac-43a1-b3c9-2e211c80bedb]     4:                 = csrf_meta_tags
F, [2016-09-15T11:25:15.388803 #18949] FATAL -- : [36ec2f26-e1ac-43a1-b3c9-2e211c80bedb]     5:                 = favicon_link_tag '/favicon.ico'
F, [2016-09-15T11:25:15.388842 #18949] FATAL -- : [36ec2f26-e1ac-43a1-b3c9-2e211c80bedb]     6:                 = stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller], media: 'all'
F, [2016-09-15T11:25:15.388880 #18949] FATAL -- : [36ec2f26-e1ac-43a1-b3c9-2e211c80bedb]     7:                 = javascript_include_tag params[:controller]
F, [2016-09-15T11:25:15.388917 #18949] FATAL -- : [36ec2f26-e1ac-43a1-b3c9-2e211c80bedb]     8:                 = yield :head
F, [2016-09-15T11:25:15.388953 #18949] FATAL -- : [36ec2f26-e1ac-43a1-b3c9-2e211c80bedb]     9:         %body.standard{ class: [yield(:body_class), params[:controller]] }
F, [2016-09-15T11:25:15.388991 #18949] FATAL -- : [36ec2f26-e1ac-43a1-b3c9-2e211c80bedb]    10:                 #wrapper= yield
F, [2016-09-15T11:25:15.389028 #18949] FATAL -- : [36ec2f26-e1ac-43a1-b3c9-2e211c80bedb]
F, [2016-09-15T11:25:15.389064 #18949] FATAL -- : [36ec2f26-e1ac-43a1-b3c9-2e211c80bedb] app/views/layouts/application.haml:7:in `_app_views_layouts_application_haml__2281947942353102831_69956393327940'
```

My `config/production.rb` is as follows:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "ontonator_xyz_#{Rails.env}"
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

### EDIT:

I can now confirm that it is Opal. Using CoffeeScript again prevented the issue from occurring.

Also, the issue is now occurring on my local machine, and I think that it's because caches of the compiled files are being generated in development mode, and these are being used in production mode. Since I did not test in development mode on the server, I did not realise.

Setting `config.consider_all_requests_local = true` fixed the problem, and it continued to work after it was removed, but stopped working as soon as any of the relevant Javascript assets were modified.

Perhaps I am wrong, but shouldn't `config.assets.compile = true` make the server compile the assets if they are not precompiled?

### EDIT 2:

It also works with precompiling the assets, however I don't understand why this should be necessary with the `config.assets.compile = true` option set.

Comment: Did you precompile your assets? Hard to say what's wrong without seeing full error message. Try temporarily enabling `config.consider_all_requests_local = true` and check full trace of error message.

Comment: I haven't precompiled my assets, but I was under the impression that if I had `config.assets.compile = true` set I wouldn't have to. Changing that preference prevents the issue from happening, so I still have no error log apart from what's already in the question. I will also edit my question with a little more information.

Comment: There's no benefit for not compiling assets in production but there's a lot to gain. So I don't understand why you don't want to just compile assets in production?